# hybrid SPA with Next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, single-page-application, server-side-rendering

The problem I'm trying to solve: there is a public part that requires ssr for seo. But there is also an application where seo is not needed and for it to be spa.
I have no experience with next js. So the question is, is it possible to "embed" a spa application in next js.
I will be happy to get any information

react-router-dom does not work with next js because of the hydration process

Comment: Have you checked out [Next.js official site](https://nextjs.org/)? It says it right there as the first sentence—hybrid static and SSR.

Comment: Of course I read it. And yes, that's exactly what it says, hybrid with SSG. And my question is about SPA, hence hybrid with CSR

Comment: Next.js is by nature a hybrid of SSG and SPA, because it _is_ a React application at the end of the day. Once hydrated, it'd work as a typical SPA with persistent states (e.g. input values, scroll positions, etc). Next.js ships with its own `router` that handles routing logics for you. In other words, you won't _embed_ a SPA into Next.js application; it _is_ a SPA app for all intents and purposes. Some might say tools like Next.js or Gatsby are just better create-react-app alternatives. Their docs has plenty of info https://nextjs.org/docs/ and I'd recommend you just start building.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the two apps separate since they have different architectures, and it will be simpler that way. Sounds like your SPA may also be secured, which is why it does not need SEO.

A good technique can be be to build both apps to static content, then achieve public URLs like this:

- https://www.example.com
- https://www.example.com/public

Both built apps could potentially be deployed to a content delivery network. Another common option is to use a reverse proxy such as NGINX or Kong. This configuration uses NGINX to serve the SPA's static content, then routes requests to the Next.js app to a Docker container:

```
server {
    server_name reverseproxy;
    listen      ssl 443;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html;
    }

    location /public {
        proxy_pass https://nextjsapp:3000/;
    }
}
```